# What exactly is "Socket Layer" referred to in SSL?

Tags: ip, layer, ssl, osi

Well I know the 7 and 4 layered models but nowhere I can find a layer called "socket".

Comment: It is it own layer. From the point of view of layer models it is an application-layer protocol.

Comment: 'Socket' is not a layer. Nor is it a protocol. It is a programming language data type used to represent an endpoint of a connection. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket : *The socket is primarily a concept used in the Transport Layer of the Internet model*.

The *socket layer* phrase is merely a well-known word combination, and is not related to the "*layers*" in OSI model sense.
It is intended to be understood by people who has little to do with all the OSI model theory.

Comment: So basically its the good old <ip:port> pairs ? Then what's with the "Layer" ?

Comment: It is hard to tell without looking at the text containing the prase you saw, but possibly it was saying that SSL handshake occurs on a socket layer **as opposed to** more high-level HTTP level (and therefore no HTTP data such as host name is known).

Comment: I see. I wasn't referring to any particular text but the "SSL" itself. I was wondering what layer the "L" is referring to.

Comment: Now I see. Yes, the common meaning of the word "_level_" is used there, not in the OSI model sense.

Answer (score 3):

In SSL, the 'layer' does not refer to the OSI or IP suite layer system, although it is associated with a given layer in each. The term 'layer' fits well because Application Layer protocols like SMTP and HTTP can simply be layered on top of it.

In the 4-layer IP Suite model, SSL/TLS is in the Application Layer, (although it is actually layered below other application layer protocols, such as HTTP).

The successor to SSL, TLS, is even named 'Transport Layer security'. That's slightly misleading in this context, but from the perspective of other Application Layer protocols, it is a layer below them, just like a Transport Layer protocol.

In the 7-layer OSI model, SSL is a 'Presentation Layer' protocol, separating it from HTTP/SMTP/... above it, and things like SOCKS and PPTP in the Session layer below it.

See wikipedia for confirmation:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model